# Driving a 12V motor with brushed ESC

Tags: motor, driver, motor-controller

For my project, I have a winch motor that takes 12V. I have a 12V battery to power it. I want to be able to set up a remote control system consisting of a receiver, transmitter, and one of those brushed motor speed controllers (ESC). For example, this ESC can be found on HobbyKing.

https://hobbyking.com/en_us/hobbywing-quicrun-60a-2s-3s-waterproof-brushed-esc-for-1-10.html

However, I am confused about the voltage ratings on the ESCs. For the input voltage, it can take up to 3S Lipo, which would be about 4.2 x 3 = 12.6V. That would work with my Lipo battery. But I am confused about the output voltage. There isn't anything written about it.

Do we assume that the output voltage to the motor is the same as the input voltage to the ESC? In my case, that would be 12V. Or will these brushed ESCs drive the motor at a lower voltage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you would be fine using this. Under "Motor Limit", it appears to be designed to drive 2S or 3S motors, which correspond to your input voltage. More likely than not it is just varying the output voltage through PWM, where full on is the supply voltage.

Answer (score 0):

If your winch motor is anything like mine you can drive up to 50 Amps starting up or more.

Your ESC will need to drive steps that are capable of more than 100 Amps with a reverse diode to match , the same back EMF current when turning off.

Yes ESC uses same voltage as motor rating. 
If current rating is 1.2A then 12V/DCR can be as high as 10x or 12A which the ESC must be  able to drive on full starts

Lower VBat results in lower torque and RPM

Comment: My project is small scale, so I am using a small dc motor paired to a gearbox. This is the exact model:

https://www.amazon.com/BEMONOC-DC-Motor-Geared-Metal/dp/B01DD7OL1K/ref=sr_1_12?ie=UTF8&qid=1525841113&sr=8-12&keywords=geared+dc+motor

The rated current is only 1.2A, and I'm not going to be putting a heavy load on it, so I'm not too worried about the current draw. 

Does the ESC also output 12V if I connect it to a 12V battery?